# How I can use Java Regex for Turkish characters to UTF-8

Tags: java, regex, unicode, turkish

I'm trying to do a regex operations in Java. But when I search in the Turkish text , I'm having trouble . For example;

```
Search Text = "Ahmet Yıldırım" or "Esin AYDEMİR" 

//The e-mail stated in part(Ex: yildirim@example.com) , trying to look in name.
Regex Strings = "yildirim" or  "aydemir".
```

Searched text is dynamically changing.Therefore , how can I solve this by using java regex pattern. Or How do I convert Turkish characters(`Ex: AYDEMİR convert to AYDEMIR`  or `Yıldırım -> Yildirim`).

Sorry, about my grammer mistakes!...

Comment: Ok but how convert to "yildirim" to "y[iı]ld[ıi]r[ıi]m". Dynamically, in every text ("İÖÜŞÇĞıöüşçğ") How can I determine this character. And convert to ("IOUSCGiouscg")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) and [`Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) flag:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("yildirim", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/XTJsMi)

`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` by default only match case-insensitively for characters in US-ASCII character set. `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` modifies the behavior to make it match case-insensitively for all Unicode characters.

Do note that Unicode case-insensitive matching in Java regex is done in a culture-insensitive manner. Therefore, `ı`, `i`, `I`, `İ` are considered the same character.

Depending on your use case, you might want to use `Pattern.LITERAL` if you want to disable all metacharacters in the pattern, or only escape literal parts of the pattern with [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Do you know of a way to achieve the same behavior in .NET? Just curious.

Comment: @stribizhev: That's a good question. I thought `IgnoreCase | CulturalInvariant` would work, but it turns out that it doesn't. You might want to ask a new question? (I also want to know the answer)

Comment: @stribizhev: Actually, in .NET, we can solve this problem by setting the appropriate culture (in this case, Turkish) - though it means that you must at least know the language of the input before you process it.

Comment: I also checked `CultureInvariant`  flag at first. I will study this when I have some time.

Answer (score 8):

The question in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117953/how-i-can-use-java-regex-for-turkish-characters-to-utf-8#comment52128586_32117953) is more complicated than the original one.

You can use

```
string=Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{Mn}", "");
```

to convert `"İÖÜŞÇĞıöüşçğ"` to `"IOUSCGıouscg"` which is already sufficient for a case insensitive match as pointed [out by nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118382/2711488). If you want to perform a case sensitive match, you have to add a `.replace('ı', 'i')` to match `ı` with `i`.

Comment: Thanks your advice.I think I had a little trouble in explaining my problem, But I did solve my problem with this answer.

Comment: @Holger: How do you get a link to a comment? Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu: right-click on the date/time right beside the user name and select “copy link location”.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this pattern.

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumericWithWhiteSpace(String text) {
        return text != null && text.matches("^[\\p{L}\\p{N}ın\\s]*$");
    }
```

> \p{L} matches a single code point in the category "letter".
>
> \p{N} matches any kind of numeric character in any script.

Answer (score -1):

git hub url for replacing the Turkish char https://gist.github.com/onuryilmaz/6034569

in java `string.matches(".*[İÖÜŞÇĞıöüşçğ]*.")` will check whether the String contains Turkish charters.

Comment: Can you edit your answer by surrounding the code snippet in back-ticks? That would improve readability.